# preferred location for web app files, outside of /var/www

Tags: apache2

I am very new to Linux, and I just installed Ubuntu. It really is exciting and I already installed my own apache and mysql. 
The server is running.

I have my website's files under `/var/www` but some files are excluded from user access. In my windows environment I put them under `C:/Special` and I wish to know where I should put them under Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for wanting them outside of /var/www as opposed to, for example, giving yourself or others access to modify files in /var/www?

Comment: Some of the files are scripts that should be run under the system exclusively, and not by users. Its a security measure

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in your home folder (i.e. /home/user/www) and change the Directory and DocumentRoot directive in your Apache config. If you do it this way only the user 'user' will be able to see the files but of course you still need the user 'root' to run the apache daemon not 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

You should simple make a directory under /var/www which is not accessible for other users

```
chmod o-rwx /var/www/special
```

for full security you should also mark the files inside this directory with the same permissions.